# Java/maven: how to force my project to use the local version of a dependency?

Tags: java, maven

Might be best explained with an example:

- I have 2 custom maven projects (let's call them projectX and projectY).
- projectY is dependent on projectX. projectX has been added to projectY via

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.projectx.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>projectx.core</artifactId>
      <version>(0.0),</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- In projectX, I made some changes to Constants.java and added a new public constant.
- I'm trying to access this new constant in projectY, but it's not working. I'm getting this error => "cannot find symbol: insert-constant-name-here"
- It seems to me that projectY is still referencing an older version of projectX. I believe projectY is still referencing whatever the latest version of projectX is that's available in our remote mvn repo.
- I have a feeling that if I build projectX and push it to the remote mvn repo, everything will work fine. I cannot do this yet as I need to make more changes to projectX.

Comment: Debug with `mvn -X ...` and confirm your theory first.

Comment: Have you tried `mvn -U clean install ` ?

Comment: you know that mvn clean install -o work in offline assuming you build the other project has -SNAPSHOT if not you can always do the ugly way build the Jar and define in dependency the systemPath to the jar himself

Comment: I would recommend to take a deep look into https://maven.apache.org/resolver/remote-repository-filtering.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>groupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>artifactId</artifactId>
  <version>version</version>
  <scope>system</scope>
  <systemPath>file path/jar-file.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

You can Add this into your `pom.xml` file then update your project.

Comment: systemPath is nearly always a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: Version ranges like `(0,0),` are evil.

Sure, they are allowed in Maven, but they cause all kind of pain, and they are considered deprecated by many.

So, what should you do?

If your project Y and project X are so tightly coupled that project Y always needs the latest version of project X, you usually set up a multi-module project with both of them. Then you always build both together, problem solved.

If this is not the way for you to go, you can use a `-SNAPSHOT` version of project X in project Y while developing. This allows for easier updates because you do not always need to change the version of the dependency when you rebuild X. Beware, though, that if you build the same SNAPSHOT versions locally and on the build server, it might be confusing which one actually "wins" and is drawn, depending on the specified update policy.